# Getting the MySQL results to the route file

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous, repository

So having a file called `mobile.js`, I create a connection to the database, with a function that calls in a query and returns a set of mobile phones:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    //database information
});

module.exports = 
{
    getAllModels: function()
    {
        pool.getConnection( function( err, connection )
        {
            connection.query("SELECT model FROM product", function( err, res, fie)
            {
                if( err ) throw err;
                connection.release();
                //console.log(res);
                return res;
            });
        });
    }
};
```

Now, uncommenting the code above I do get a JSON object `[{model: 'LG'}, {model: 'Samsung'}, ...]`, but when I try to reach that variable in the `index.js` route file via:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var mobileRepo = require('../repositories/mobile');

router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var modeli = mobileRepo.getAllModels();
  console.log(modeli);

  res.render('index');
});

module.exports = router;
```

the variable `modeli` is going to be `undefined`.

Through my **current** research, I know that this happens because `connection.query` is an async/threaded function, but what I can't find anywhere and am trying to figure out is how to escape this?

Basically, how do combine the route and the connection result, thus allowing for the variable to pick up the query result?

I'd also very happily accept any good reads about the topic or Node.js in general, since I'm currently learning it!

Thanks for reading!

**EDIT:** I can even see that the query results in come in after the page loads, but I still have no idea how to make the query wait.

```
Tue, 10 Nov 2015 00:42:06 GMT expressnodejs:server Listening on port 3000
undefined <--- this is calling the result from index.js
GET / 200 72.216 ms - 179
[ { model: 'Samsung' }, { model: 'LG' } ] <--- calling result from mobile.js when query is done
```

One thing that crossed my mind is to create an outcome function:

```
module.exports = 
{
    getAllModels: function( outcome )
    {
        pool.getConnection( function( err, connection )
        {
            connection.query("SELECT model FROM product", function( err, res, fie)
            {
                //snip
                outcome( res );
}}}};
```

But doesn't that break the whole idea of why Node.js is so fast in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outcome` is exactly what you need and it's called a `callback` and this is the right way to make async code work.

You also gonna need to change the way you call the function.

```
mobileRepo.getAllModels(function(modeli){
    console.log(modeli);
    res.render('index');
});
```

Comment: So, I that **is** what I'm supposed to do.. Thanks for the late answer! I'll mark it as answered.